# Time Complexity of smallest range of elements containing at least 1 element from each of the k lists

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

Can someone please elaborate how is the time complexity of this function  O(n^2 * k)? I understand the for loop within the while loop will execute atmost k times.But what I don't understand is the n^2 term.

```
void findSmallestRange(int arr[][N], int n, int k)
{
  int i,minval,maxval,minrange,minel,maxel,flag,minind;

  //initializing to 0 index;
  for(i = 0;i <= k;i++) 
    ptr[i] = 0;

  minrange = INT_MAX;

  while(1)       
  {
      // for mainting the index of list containing the minimum element
      minind = -1; 
      minval = INT_MAX;
      maxval = INT_MIN;
      flag = 0;

      //iterating over all the list
      for(i = 0;i < k;i++)   
      {    
          // if every element of list[i] is traversed then break the loop
          if(ptr[i] == n)   
          {
            flag = 1;
            break;
          }
          // find minimum value among all the list elements pointing by the ptr[] array 
          if(ptr[i] < n && arr[i][ptr[i]] < minval)  
          {
              minind=i;  // update the index of the list
              minval=arr[i][ptr[i]];
          }
          // find maximum value among all the list elements pointing by the ptr[] array
          if(ptr[i] < n && arr[i][ptr[i]] > maxval)    
          {
              maxval = arr[i][ptr[i]];
          }
      }

      //if any list exhaust we will not get any better answer ,so break the while loop
      if(flag) 
        break;

      ptr[minind]++;

      //updating the minrange
      if((maxval-minval) < minrange)  
      {
          minel = minval;
          maxel = maxval;
          minrange = maxel - minel;
      }
  }

  printf("The smallest range is [%d , %d]\n",minel,maxel);
}
```

Comment: `n^2` **IS** the two nested loops. And `k` is simply the number of lists (test data)

Comment: Are you sure this is `O(n^2 * k)`? Isn't it `O(n * k^2)`?

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** This actually proves a complexity of `O(n * k^2)` - I am not (yet) deleting this because maybe someone will find a flaw in my reasoning, or maybe this is the real complexity...

The inner loop is `O(k)` as you already noticed, the question is how much times will the outer loop be executed?

1. The outer loop will stop being executed as soon as one of the value in `ptr` is `n`.
2. Your start with `ptr[i] = 0` for `i = 1 .. k`, and for each execution of the outer loop, you increment **a single value** in `ptr`.

The worst-possible case is when all the value in `ptr` are increment successively, i.e. when you get:

```
ptr = 0 0 0 ... 0
ptr = 1 0 0 ... 0
ptr = 1 1 0 ... 0
...
ptr = 1 1 1 ... 1
ptr = 2 1 1 ... 1
```

With this scenario, the loop will stop at the following iteration:

```
ptr = n (n-1) (n-1) ... (n-1)
```

How much time does it require to go from `0 0 0 ... 0` to `n (n-1) (n-1) ... (n-1)`? `O(n * k)` because it require `O(n)` for one cell to go from `1` to `n`, and you have `k` cells in `ptr`.

So the total complexity seems to be `O(n * k^2)`, and not `O(n^2 * k)`...